# Django ManyToMany with quantity

Tags: python, django

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to model something in Django that I've conceptualized. I know that it is a many to many relationship... however it is sort of self referential and has a quantity involved. I imagine this requires a bridge model of some sort, which I have, but now how do I edit them in the admin page?

What I have is a Component class. For example, a 'screw' is a component, and it requires no further components to create it. But so is a 'housing', which requires 4 screws to hold it together. That housing could then go into a manifold and the manifold could go into a vehicle and so forth.

Each thing could potentially be a component of another thing if that makes sense. I've put all of the screws and bolts and such into the database through the admin edit page. But now I want to start putting in more complex assemblies. I could just create an Assembly class which has a list of one or more components. But I'm still left with the problem that this assembly could go into a larger assembly zero or more times.

How do I represent that?

currently I have

```
class ComponentBase(models.Model)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   class Meta:
     abstract = True
     ordering = ['name']


class ItemComponent(ComponentBase):
   components = models.ManyToManyField('ItemComponentWithQuantity', blank=True)



class ItemComponentWithQuantity(ItemComponent):
   quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

assuming this is the correct way to model this (is it?) how do I get the admin edit form to set this up a bit like a spreadsheet or list?

like

```
name: manifold assembly
components:
   10x screws
   10x bolts
   1x assembly housing
```

The components field should only show the ones that have been added and the quantity. Not all possible components.

i had my model originally set up to have components = models.ManyToManyField('ItemComponent', blank=True). This caused the admin panel to have a list of all the existing ItemComponents as expected, but obviously no quantities.

Adding the ItemComponentWithQuantity class in, I changed the manytomanyfield to ItemComponentWithQuantity. But now the admin components field is empty.

I hope I'm making sense here. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

thanks in advance.
EK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can just have a single model and make it a recursive model where it is in a relationship with itself

```
component = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i also advice you add an extra field for quantity instead of creating a whole model for that. Hope this works.

Answer (score 2):

The inheritance that you're doing is making this too complicated. You can model this a different way. Change your `ComponentBase` to a basic model.Model (not abstract) named `Assembly`. Change `ItemComponent` to just `Component`. Lastly change your `ItemComponentWithQuantity` to `AssemblyComponent`.

The `AssemblyComponent` should have the fields

- `assembly` - ForeignKey to `Assembly`
- `component` - ForeignKey to `Component`
- `quantity` - IntegerField

Make another model `AssemblyAssembly` with the fields

- `assembly_parent` - ForeignKey to `Assembly`
- `assembly_child` - ForeignKey to `Assembly`
- `quantity` - IntegerField

You would then create either a Tabular or Stacked inline admin (depends on desired user experience) for both `AssemblyComponent` and `AssemblyAssembly`. Be sure to set [fk_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.fk_name) in the `AssemblyAssembly` to point to the `assembly_parent` as the fk_name because you have two foreign key fields referencing the same model. You can use a `raw_id_field` for the `assembly_child` if there will be a lot of possible assemblies in the system. Use the inline admins for the `Assembly` admin.

- For more about inline admins, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

That will give you roughly the admin UI that you want with the exception that component and assembly links will be in separate inline admins.

Comment: or not... apparently the combobox on the admin field where the existing components should be is empty? The quantity is popping in as one, which is fine. But there isn't anything in the dropdown.

Comment: You probably need to add a model admin for `Component` because you need a way to add these separate of the `Assembly` model. Once you do that, you should see a + sign next to the drop down for `Component` items in the `AssemblyComponent` inline admins.